# creating a list filled with alike values of two different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

The whole point of me doing this is to learn how to code python without using the built in functions that are given, such as `sort()`, `max()`, and `min()`. I need to create a function that takes 2 lists as arguments and creates a new list filled with alike values of the 2 lists that are being passed to the function. The new_list cannot take any duplicates so if `list1= [1,2,2,3,4]` and `list2 = [1,2,2,3,4]` my `new_list` should = `[1,2,3,4]`. the problem with the function I have is that I use the python built in function `in` to check if `x` is not in `new_list`. How can I extend this function to check if the value is already within `new_list` without using python's built-in functions?

```
def alike_values(list1, list2):
   new_list = []
   for i in list1:
       for x in list2:
           if i == x and x not in new_list:
              new_list.append(i)
   return new_list
```

Comment: Use `for` and iterate over all items or maintain a 'dict'

Comment: I can understand avoiding the use of built-ins like `max` and `min` in order to learn how to code basic algorithms... but avoiding the use of `in` is taking this a little too far, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second function, which checks if the value is already contained in the list:

```
def alike_values(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    for i in list1:
        for x in list2:
            if i == x and not in_list(new_list, x):
                new_list.append(i)
    return new_list

def in_list(li, val):
    for i in li:
        if i == val:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: needs to be 1 single function.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a single line. Just use basic set properties. The code to do so is given below.

```
combined_list = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without built in functions, but I'm sure you wont be able to order them. what you could do is:

```
    def alike_values(list1, list2):
        combined_list = sorted(list1 + list2)
        new_list = list(set(combined_list))
        return new_list
```